# A silly coincidence: $\frac{c}{\rm year}\approx 9.81 {\rm m/s^2}$

Tags: gravity, speed-of-light, equivalence-principle

Long ago, I sat and wondered about the equivalence of the gravitational pull on my body and upward acceleration.  If I am not wrong, there is no way to distinguish between sitting on my chair here on earth, feeling pulled into the chair by gravity, and accelerating upward at 9.81 $m/s^2$.  I then thought,"well, all that acceleration would get you to the speed of light eventually" neglecting special relativity.  Then I thought, isn't it funny that our orbit around the sun brings us back to our original position (as though to counteract this).  So, I calculated the speed we would reach in a year if we were accelerating at $g$ constantly for one year.  It turns out that this number is equal to the speed of light to within about 1%.  It is an odd coincidence.  It doesn't work out as well for the other terrestrial planets.  Has anyone ever wondered about this?  Does it mean anything?

Comment: it's a coincidence. Not an odd one. We could pull out many many other coincidences "within 1%" (btw, it's within 3% when I check). Plus, what you are referring to is the equivalence principle, from general relativity. It's a bit peculiar to take GR as a starting point and then "neglecting special relativity".

Comment: @BarbaudJulien's comment really is the answer. [Wikipedia also writes about it, even explicitly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_coincidence)

Comment: I mention this approximation as providing a rule of thumb for [space travel under constant acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_travel_under_constant_acceleration) in [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36778) answer, just in case you want to calculate what speed would _really_ be reached after a year. It'll be quite a bit less than $c$ because of relativistic velocity addition.

Answer (score 3):

It's a coincidence. There is no particular relationship between a planet's surface gravity (which depends on the planet's mass and radius) and the length of its year (which depends on the Sun's mass and the orbital radius).

The agreement is not quite as good as you say: in fact $g\cdot 1\text{ yr} \approx 1.03c$.

Also, this is not really the speed you would reach if you accelerated from rest at $g$ for 1 year of proper time in the absence of gravity (obviously, since it's larger than $c$). The actual speed you would reach is $c\tanh (g\cdot 1\text{ yr}/c) \approx 0.77c$.

Answer (score 1):

The Moon has the same length of year as the Earth, as indeed do the various bits of space rubble in the L4 and L5 Lagrange points, and all these objects have different values for the gravitational acceleration at their surface. So there is nothing special about multiplying the surface gravity by the orbital period. The result you have obtained is just a coincidence.